# Java game development - Trouble with title screen

Tags: java, swing

I was wondering if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong here.  I'm coding a basic game in java and I want to add a title screen to the beginning.  Basically, if the player clicks '1', I want the game to begin.  However, when I try and change the graphics, the screen is blank, but the keys for the game still work and the game is definitely updating itself.  It just isn't showing anything.  Here are the files.  Any help would be very much appreciated!

FarthornWindow.java:

```
package com.Farthorn.game;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class FarthornWindow extends Canvas
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 2297047193030106579L;
private JFrame frame;
private TitleScreen ts;

public FarthornWindow(int width, int  height)
{
    ts = new TitleScreen(this);
    frame = new JFrame("Farthorn - Kos");
    frame.setSize(width, height);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(ts);
    frame.setVisible(true); 
    ts.start();
}

public JFrame getFrame()
{
    return frame;
}

}
```

TitleScreen.java:

```
package com.Farthorn.game;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

public class TitleScreen extends Canvas implements Runnable
{
FarthornWindow window;
private boolean running = false;
private Thread thread;
private BufferStrategy bs;

public TitleScreen(FarthornWindow window)
{
    this.window = window;
    this.addKeyListener(new MenuInput(this));
}

public synchronized void start()
{
    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

public synchronized void stop()
{
    try
    {
        thread.join();
        running = false;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void run() 
{
    this.requestFocus();
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
    double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
    double delta = 0;
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int frames = 0;
    while (running)
    {
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
        lastTime = now;
        while (delta >= 1)
        {
            tick();
            delta--;
        }
        if (running)
        {
            render();
        }
        frames++;

        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000)
        {
            timer += 1000;
            System.out.println("FPS1 " + frames);
            frames = 0;
        }
    }
    stop();
}

private void tick()
{       

}

private void render()
{
    bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null)
    {
        this.createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }

    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, Game.WIDTH, Game.HEIGHT);

    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}

public FarthornWindow getWindow()
{
    return window;
}

public void setRunning(boolean r)
{
    running = r;
}


}
```

Game.java:

```
package com.Farthorn.game;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = -4431078110090264106L;
public final static int WIDTH = 640;
public final static int HEIGHT = WIDTH / 12 * 9;

private Thread thread;
private boolean running = false;
private CharacterHandler cHandler;
private ObjectHandler oHandler;
public int change = 0;

private static String mapBackgroundTop = "/Users/myName/Desktop/FarthornPics/background_top.png";
private static String mapBackgroundBottom = "/Users/myName/Desktop/FarthornPics/background_bottom.png";
private static String plant1 = "/Users/myName/Desktop/FarthornPics/PlantEnemy1.png";
private static String animal1 = "/Users/myName/Desktop/FarthornPics/DumbEnemy1Still.png";

private Image backgroundTop;
private Image backgroundBottom;

private int baseheight = HEIGHT/2+64;

public Game()
{
    ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon(mapBackgroundTop);
    backgroundTop = i.getImage();
    i = new ImageIcon(mapBackgroundBottom);
    backgroundBottom = i.getImage();

    cHandler = new CharacterHandler();
    oHandler = new ObjectHandler();

    Player p1 = new Player(ID.Player, WIDTH/2-32, HEIGHT/2, oHandler, cHandler);
    cHandler.addCharacter(p1);
    /*
    cHandler.addCharacter(new PlantEnemy(ID.PlantEnemy, WIDTH+180, HEIGHT/2+104, p1, plant1));
    cHandler.addCharacter(new PlantEnemy(ID.PlantEnemy, WIDTH+195, HEIGHT/2+104, p1, plant1));
    cHandler.addCharacter(new PlantEnemy(ID.PlantEnemy, WIDTH+210, HEIGHT/2+104, p1, plant1));
    cHandler.addCharacter(new PlantEnemy(ID.PlantEnemy, WIDTH+225, HEIGHT/2+104, p1, plant1));
    cHandler.addCharacter(new PlantEnemy(ID.PlantEnemy, WIDTH+240, HEIGHT/2+104, p1, plant1));
    cHandler.addCharacter(new PlantEnemy(ID.PlantEnemy, WIDTH+255, HEIGHT/2+104, p1, plant1));
    cHandler.addCharacter(new PlantEnemy(ID.PlantEnemy, WIDTH+270, HEIGHT/2+104, p1, plant1));
    cHandler.addCharacter(new PlantEnemy(ID.PlantEnemy, WIDTH+285, HEIGHT/2+104, p1, plant1));
    cHandler.addCharacter(new PlantEnemy(ID.PlantEnemy, WIDTH+300, HEIGHT/2+104, p1, plant1));
    cHandler.addCharacter(new PlantEnemy(ID.PlantEnemy, WIDTH+315, HEIGHT/2+104, p1, plant1));
    */

    cHandler.addCharacter(new DumbEnemy(ID.DumbEnemy, (int)2*WIDTH, HEIGHT/2+104, p1, animal1));

    oHandler.addObject(new HUD(ID.HUD, 10, 10, cHandler));
    oHandler.addObject(new Platform(ID.Platform, -100, Game.HEIGHT/2+124, 2400, 1, (Player) cHandler.characters.get(0)));
    oHandler.addObject(new Platform(ID.Platform, 2*WIDTH, baseheight+20, 100, 1, (Player) cHandler.characters.get(0)));

    this.addKeyListener(new KeyInput((Player) cHandler.characters.get(0)));
    this.addMouseListener(new MouseInput(((Player) cHandler.characters.get(0))));

    // FarthornWindow window = new FarthornWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, this);
}

public synchronized void start()
{
    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

public synchronized void stop()
{
    try
    {
        thread.join();
        running = false;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void run() 
{
    this.requestFocus();

    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
    double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
    double delta = 0;
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int frames = 0;
    while (running)
    {
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
        lastTime = now;
        while (delta >= 1)
        {
            tick();
            delta--;
        }
        if (running)
        {
            render();
        }
        frames++;

        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000)
        {
            timer += 1000;
            System.out.println("FPS " + frames);
            frames = 0;
        }
    }
    stop();
}

private void tick()
{       
    int deltaX = 0;
    int afterX = 0;

    deltaX = cHandler.characters.get(0).getX();

    oHandler.tick();
    cHandler.tick();

    deltaX = cHandler.characters.get(0).getX();
    if (deltaX != afterX)
        change = (afterX-deltaX);
    else
        change = 0;
}

private void render()
{
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null)
    {
        this.createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.drawImage(backgroundTop, 0+change, 0, null);
    g.drawImage(backgroundBottom, 0+change, 364, null);

    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    oHandler.render(g);
    cHandler.render(g);

    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}

public int getChange()
{
    return change;
}


public static int clamp(int var, int min, int max)
{
    if (var >= max)
    {
        return var = max;
    }
    else if (var <= min){
        return var = min;
    }
    else
        return var;
}


public static boolean isSolid(Player player, ObjectHandler oHandler)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < oHandler.objects.size(); i++)
    {
        GameObject temp = oHandler.objects.get(i);
        if (temp.getId() == ID.Platform)
        {
            if (((Platform) temp).getRect().intersects(player.getFeet()))
            {
                player.setVelY(0);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

}
```

MenuInput.java:

```
package com.Farthorn.game;

import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class MenuInput extends KeyAdapter
{
private TitleScreen ts;
public MenuInput(TitleScreen ts)
{
    this.ts = ts;
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_1)
    {
        ts.setRunning(false);
        ts.getWindow().getFrame().remove(ts);
        Game game = new Game();
        ts.getWindow().getFrame().add(game);
        game.start();
    }
}
}
```

KeyInput.java:

```
package com.Farthorn.game;

import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class KeyInput extends KeyAdapter
{
private boolean[] pressed = new boolean[4];
private Player player;
public KeyInput(Player player)
{
    this.player = player;
    for (int i = 0; i < pressed.length; i++)
        pressed[i] = false;
}

public class jumpThread implements Runnable
{
    long jumpingTime = 200;
    public void run() {
        try
        {
            player.setVelY(-5);
            Thread.sleep(jumpingTime);
            jumpingTime = 150;
            player.setVelY(-3);
            Thread.sleep(jumpingTime);
            jumpingTime = 50;
            player.setVelY(-2);
            Thread.sleep(jumpingTime);
            player.setLanding(true);
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            new Thread(this).start();
        }
    }
}

public class walkThread implements Runnable
{
    long walkingTime = 200;
    public void run() 
    {
        try {
            while (player.getWalking() == true)
            {
                    player.setCharImage("/Users/myName/Desktop/FarthornPics/charWalking1.png");
                Thread.sleep(walkingTime);
                    player.setCharImage("/Users/myName/Desktop/FarthornPics/charWalking2.png");
                Thread.sleep(walkingTime);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{   
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE){
        System.exit(0);
    }
    if (player.getID() == ID.Player)
    {
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_A)
        {
            player.setWalking(true);
            new Thread(new walkThread()).start();
            player.setVelX(-5);
            pressed[0] = true;
        }
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_D)
        {
            new Thread(new walkThread()).start();
            player.setVelX(5);
            pressed[1] = true;
            player.setWalking(true);
        }
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_W)
        {
            new Thread(new jumpThread()).start();
            pressed[2] = true;
        }

    }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
{
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_A)
    {
        pressed[0] = false;
    }
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_D)
    {
        pressed[1] = false;
    }

    if (!pressed[0] && !pressed[1])
    {
        player.setWalking(false);
        player.setVelX(0);
    }
}
}
```

RunMethod.java:

```
package com.Farthorn.game;

public class RunMethod {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    new FarthornWindow(Game.WIDTH, Game.HEIGHT);
}

}
```

Comment: I'm immediately suspicious of your use of threads; Swing is single-threaded.

Comment: The real problem though is that you don't use `getGraphics()` to paint in AWT; you must override `paintComponent()`. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/

Comment: @Saposhiente The OP isn't really using Swing, with the use of BufferedStrategy they are taking control of the rendering process

Comment: @Saposhiente I was trying to use a BufferedStrategy for the rendering, like MadProgrammer said.  That has worked perfectly though when it was only the game that had to be rendered.  Perhaps I'd need to do things differently if I want a title screen too, but I feel like my current way could work.

Comment: Add some debug statements to ensure that the states are we switched. Reduce your thread usages, you should be able to use a single thread that does the core rendering functionary, but "running" should be volatile. Make sure that the images are been loaded. Don't rely on magic numbers, rely on own values, the width and height of your components aren't always going to be what you might expect

Comment: @MadProgrammer My bad, haven't worked with BufferedStrategy before. Agree that you should use `println` to determine whether the right method is being called and therefore isolate the problem.

Comment: I'm just going to reiterate one point, you only need ONE core thread, it should then be calling some kind of "update" method and some kind of "render" method, which could be achieved through the use of an interface which instances of which could be switched (ie menu and game)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Okay I'll try and implement what you just said here and get back to you. Thanks for your help!